# React redirect after login problem with using hooks incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a login page in react and after receiving the cookie I am using  `history.push('/dashboard');` to redirect to bring the user to the dashboard page but I keep getting the following error:
I don't have more than one react copy, I think I am breaking the rules of hooks but I don't quite understand what those are.

[image]

Here is my full onSubmit method:

```
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/api/authenticate', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        const history = useHistory();
        history.push('/dashboard');
      } else {
        const error = new Error(res.error);
        throw error;
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      alert('Error logging in please try again');
    });
  }
```

Comment: are you using class based component?

Comment: You can't use `const history = useHistory();` inside a regular function, but only in a functional component scope.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official documentation - [Only Call Hooks at the Top Level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders